# (Basic?) File compiles fine, doesn't execute as intended

Tags: python, import, atom-editor

> I'm running this on cygwin using atom as my editor. Python3.

Hi,

Basic Python question that really baffles me. I've looked around on SO and found a lot of questions regarding similiar issues, but can't find one that covers the issue I'm facing.

Before I go into details; this is an assignment that I'm working on so if you don't want to spill "all the beans", then just give me some sort of guidance.

I've been tasked with splitting a chat-bot into two files, one that handles the main() function and one that handles all the possible functions that the input-choices from main() uses.

For some reason both files compile fine, but when I call main.py

> (either by >python main.py  // // // // or by > ./main.py)

I get no prompt at all. Neither do I get a prompt while trying the same with marvin.py.

Both files are in the same directory.

This is main():

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import marvin

def main():
    """
    This is the main method, I call it main by convention.
    Its an eternal loop, until q is pressed.
    It should check the choice done by the user and call a appropriate
    function.
    """

    while True:
        menu()
        choice = input("--> ")

        if choice == "q":
            print("Bye, bye - and welcome back anytime!")
            return

        elif choice == "1":
            myNameIs()

        elif choice == "2":
            yearsToSec()

        elif choice == "3":
            weightOnMoon()

        elif choice == "4":
            minsToHours()

        elif choice == "5":
            celToFahr()

        elif choice == "6":
            multiplyWord()

        elif choice == "7":
            randNumber()

        elif choice == "8":
            sumAndAverage()

        elif choice == "9":
            gradeFromPoints()

        elif choice == "10":
            areaFromRadius()

        elif choice == "11":
            calcHypotenuse()

        elif choice == "12":
            checkNumber()

        else:
            print("That is not a valid choice. You can only choose from the menu.")

            input("\nPress enter to continue...")



            if __name__ == "__main__":
                main()
```

As you can see I do import marvin after the environment-variables have been loaded. 
There are no indentation errors or anything else when compiling either files (as mentioned above).

Disclaimer: I don't think you need to read marvin, tbh...

And this is marvin.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from random import randint
import math


def meImage():
    """
    Store my ascii image in a separat variabel as a raw string
    """
    return r"""
                _______
               _/       \_
              / |       | \
             /  |__   __|  \
            |__/((o| |o))\__|
            |      | |      |
            |\     |_|     /|
            | \           / |
             \| /  ___  \ |/
              \ | / _ \ | /
               \_________/
                _|_____|_
           ____|_________|____
          /                   \
    """


def menu():
    """
    Display the menu with the options that Marvin can do.
    """
    print(chr(27) + "[2J" + chr(27) + "[;H")
    print(meImage())
    print("Welcome.\nMy name is Ragnar.\nWhat can I do for you?\n")
    print("1) Present yourself to Ragnar.")
    print("2) Have Ragnar calculate your minimum age (in seconds).")
    print("3) Have Ragnar calculate weight on the moon.")
    print("4) Try Ragnar's abilities by having him calculate minutes to hour(s).")
    print("5) Have Ragnar calculate Fahrenheit from Celcius.")
    print("6) See if Ragnar can multiply a word of your liking by a factor of your choice.")
    print("7) Have Ragnar print 10 numbers within a range of your choice.")
    print("8) Keep entering numbers and have Ragnar print their sum and average.")
    print("9) Let Ragnar calculate your grade by entering your score!.")
    print("10) Let Ragnar calculate the area of a circle with the radius of your choice.")
    print("11) Let Ragnar calculate the hypotenuse of a triangle with the sides of your choice.")
    print("12) Have Ragnar compare a given number to your previous number.")
    print("q) Quit.")


def myNameIs():
    """
    Read the users name and say hello to Marvin.
    """
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    print("\nMarvin says:\n")
    print("Hello %s - your awesomeness!" % name)
    print("What can I do you for?!")


def yearsToSec():
    """
    Calculate your age (years) to seconds
    """

    years = input("How many years are you?\n")
    seconds = int(years) * (365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    print(str(years) + " would give you " + str(seconds) + " seconds.")
    return

def weightOnMoon():
    """
    Calculate your weight on the moon
    """

    weight = input("What is your weight (in kiloes)?\n")
    moonGrav = float(weight) * .2
    print(str(weight) + " kiloes would weigh be the same as " + str(moonGrav) + " kiloes on the moon.")

def minsToHours():
    """
    Calculate hours from minutes
    """

    minutes = input("How many minutes would you want to converted to hour(s)?\n")
    hours = float(format(float(minutes) / 60, '.2f'))
    print(str(minutes) + " hours is " + str(hours) + " hours")

def celToFahr():
    """
    Calculate celcius to Fahrenheit
    """

    cel = input("Please insert Celcius to be calculated to Fahrenheit.\n")
    fah = float(format(float(cel) * 1.8 + 32, '.2f'))
    print(str(cel) + " is " + str(fah) + " in Fahrenheit units.")

def multiplyWord():
    """
    Multiply word n-times
    """

    word = input("Please enter the word.\n")
    factor = input("And please give me the product to multiply it by!")
    word *= int(factor)
    print("The word is:\n" + str(word))

def randNumber():
    """
    Adds 10 random numbers (depending on user range)
    to a string.
    """

    rangeMin = input("What is the lower number in your range?\n")
    rangeMax = input("What is the higher number in your range?\n")
    sequence = ""
    for num in range(0, 10):
        sequence += str(randint(int(rangeMin), int(rangeMax))) + ", "
        num = num
    print("The random sequence is:\n" + sequence[:-2])

def sumAndAverage():
    """
    Adds numbers to the sum and calculate the average value of the input(s)
    """

    summa = 0
    count = 0
    temp = input("Please enter a number to be added to the sum. \nEnter 'q' if you wish to finish!\n")
    while True:
        if temp == "q":
            print("The sum of your numbers are: " + str(summa) + "\nAnd the average is: " + str(summa/count))
            return
        else:
            try:
                summa += int(temp)
                count += 1
                temp = input("Please enter a number to be added to the sum. \nEnter 'q' if you wish to finish!\n")
            except ValueError:
                print("That's not an int! \nPlease try again!")


def gradeFromPoints():
    """
    Shows the user's grade based on his / her points
    """

    points = input("How many points did you score?\n")
    if(float(points) >= 1 and float(points) <= 100):
        points = float(points) / 100

    if float(points) >= 0.9:
        print("You got an A!")

    elif float(points) >= 0.8 and float(points) < 0.9:
        print("You got a B!")

    elif float(points) >= 0.7 and float(points) < 0.8:
        print("You got a C!")

    elif float(points) >= 0.6 and float(points) < 0.7:
        print("You got a D!")

    else:
        print("You failed the class")

def areaFromRadius():
    """
    Calculates a circles area based on it's radius
    """

    radius = input("What is the circle's radius?\n")
    area = (float(radius) * float(radius)) * 3.1416
    print("The area of the circle is: " + str(format(area, '.2f')))
    print("This was calculated with this formula: (radius^2) * 3.1416")

def calcHypotenuse():
    """
    Calculates a triangle's hypotenuse based on it's sides
    """
    side1 = input("How long is the first side?\n")
    side2 = input("How long is the second side?\n")
    hypotenuse = math.sqrt((float(side1) * float(side1)) + (float(side2) * float(side2)))
    print("The hypotenuse is: " + str(hypotenuse))

def compareNumbers(a, b):
    """
    Compares two numbers
    """
    if (a > b):
        print("Your previous number was larger!")
        return a
    elif (a < b):
        print("Your new number was larger!")
        return b
    else:
        print("They were equal!")
        return a

def validateInt(a):
    """
    Validates that an input is an integer
    """
    if a == 'q':
        return a
    else:
        flag = False
        while (flag == False):
            try:
                a = int(a)
                flag = True
            except ValueError:
                print("That's not an int! \nPlease try again!")
                a = input("Try again!\n")
    return a




def checkNumber(prev="first"):
    """
    Checks the number
    """
    print("\n=================\n")

    if prev == "first":
        prev = validateInt(input("Please input a number. Press 'q' if you wish to end\n"))
        print("\n=================\n")
        new = validateInt(input("Please input a number. Press 'q' if you wish to end\n"))
        if new == 'q' or prev == 'q':
            print("You have exited the loop\n")
            return
        else:
            compareNumbers(int(prev), int(new))
            checkNumber(str(new))
    else:
        new = validateInt(input("Please input a number. Press 'q' if you wish to end\n"))
        if new == 'q':
            print("You have exited the loop!\n")
            return
        else:
            compareNumbers(int(prev), int(new))
            checkNumber(str(new))
```

> FULL DISCLAIMER: I'm sure there are bunches of improvments I can do,
>   but I'm only interested in understanding why the files won't execute
>   even though they compile fine...

Comment: "there are no indentation errors..." Yes there is: and it's the             `if __name__ == "__main__":
                main()` part which should be unindented (the `if`, I mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

should not be indented.

In your current code, the `main()` method is run in the `else` block, but you never get there because the program won't start because you just **define** the `main()` method but never **execute** it.

Unindent it and it will be executed as it won't be in a function definition anymore.

Comment: Please validate my answer if it solves your problem @geostocker ;-)

Comment: Will do now, was on cooldown or something just now.
I'm assuming the indented part you mentioned is sort of like a pageLoad() or init() function?

Comment: In your original code, the `main()` **call** was in your `main()` **function definition**, which means Python won't run it but will evaluate it (like "remember it"). Then you can call it wherever you like. But it appears that your file ends after the `main()` function definition, so Python stops. You have to tell him "now, go run my main() function".
The `if __name__ == "__main__":` is not relevant here (it just tells Python to run this if the user ran the script from the command-line - and not from an import), but the `main()` line after this `if` tells Python to actually run this function.

Answer (score 0):

The functions defined in marvin.py are not globals in main.py; they are members of the marvin module object. So, this:

```
elif choice == "1": myNameIs()
```

should be changed to this:

```
elif choice == "1": marvin.myNameIs()
```

The same goes for the rest of the places where main.py is using functions from marvin.py.